# Take perfect backup with mysqldump

Tags: mysql, database, backup, dump, database-dump

How can I make a perfect backup of mysql database using mysqldump?
When I am making a backup, my tables from specified database are only getting backed up. The procedures and functions are not.

Here's the backup command I am using:
(Operating system is Windows Vista.)

```
mysqldump -u username -p db1 > backup.sql
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It depends a bit on your version. Before 5.0.13 this is not possible with mysqldump.

From the mysqldump man page (v 5.1.30)

```
 --routines, -R

      Dump stored routines (functions and procedures) from the dumped
      databases. Use of this option requires the SELECT privilege for the
      mysql.proc table. The output generated by using --routines contains
      CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION statements to re-create the
      routines. However, these statements do not include attributes such
      as the routine creation and modification timestamps. This means that
      when the routines are reloaded, they will be created with the
      timestamps equal to the reload time.
      ...

      This option was added in MySQL 5.0.13. Before that, stored routines
      are not dumped. Routine DEFINER values are not dumped until MySQL
      5.0.20. This means that before 5.0.20, when routines are reloaded,
      they will be created with the definer set to the reloading user. If
      you require routines to be re-created with their original definer,
      dump and load the contents of the mysql.proc table directly as
      described earlier.
```

Comment: Exporting worked but.. importing not working..
mysqldump -u root demo -R < E:\Java\AkshayProject\Dump\DBbackup.sql is not working.

Answer (score 117):

If you want to take a full backup i.e., all databases, procedures, routines, and events without interrupting any connections:

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p -A -R -E --triggers --single-transaction > full_backup.sql
```

1. `-A` For all databases (you can also use `--all-databases`)
2. `-R` For all routines (stored procedures & triggers)
3. `-E` For all events
4. `--single-transaction` Without locking the tables i.e., without interrupting any connection (R/W).

If you want to take a backup of only specified database(s):

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p [database_name] [other_database_name] -R -e --triggers --single-transaction > database_backup.sql
```

If you want to take a backup of only a specific table in a database:

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p [database_name] [table_name] > table_backup.sql
```

If you want to take a backup of the database structure only just add `--no-data` to the previous commands:

```
mysqldump -u [username] –p[password] –-no-data [database_name] > dump_file.sql
```

`mysqldump` has many more options, which are all documented in the [`mysqldump` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) or by running `man mysqldump` at the command line.

Comment: I am having trouble loading data into mysql due to foreign key constraints, and the order of the tables dumped is not in any particular order that satisfy the foreign key constraints (dependent table before referencing table).

Comment: use can use  below for your session level.
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
if you use global make sure to set it back.

Comment: Works! Thanks! There might be a typo at `-e`. I used `-E`. But there is both, as you can see with `mysqldump --help`.

Comment: Upvoted. I assume there are no flags necessary to import such SQL dump, correct? Ie. `$ mysql -u [username] -p [new_database] << database_backup.sql`

Comment: You can also directly compress your backup like so: `mysqldump <necessary params> | gzip > backup.sql.gz`.

Answer (score 16):

Use these commands :-

```
mysqldump <other mysqldump options> --routines > outputfile.sql
```

If we want to backup ONLY the stored procedures and triggers and not the mysql tables and data then we should run something like:

```
mysqldump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt <database> > outputfile.sql
```

If you need to import them to another db/server you will have to run something like:

```
mysql <database> < outputfile.sql
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the --routines flag you will need to grant the backup user permissions to read the stored procedures:

```
GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`proc` TO <backup user>@<backup host>;
```

My minimal set of GRANT privileges for the backup user are:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ...
GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES ON <target_db>.* TO ...
GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`proc` TO ...
```

Comment: Grant privileges, that is what I was missing! +1

Comment: And also, don't forget a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I am using MySQL 5.5.40. This version has the option `--all-databases`

```
mysqldump -u<username> -p<password> --all-databases --events > /tmp/all_databases__`date +%d_%b_%Y_%H_%M_%S`.sql
```

This command will create a perfect backup of all databases in MySQL server to file named to current date-time.

Answer (score 2):

Use '-R' to backup stored procedures, but also keep in mind that if you want a consistent dump of your database while its being modified you need to use `--single-transaction` (if you only backup innodb) or `--lock-all-tables` (if you also need myisam tables)

Answer (score 1):

**On MySQL 5.7 its work for me, I'm using CentOS7.**

**For taking Dump.**

*Command :*

```
mysqldump -u user_name -p database_name -R -E > file_name.sql
```

*Exemple :*

```
mysqldump -u root -p mr_sbc_clean -R -E > mr_sbc_clean_dump.sql
```

**For deploying Dump.**

*Command :*

```
mysql -u user_name -p database_name < file_name.sql
```

*Exemple :*

```
mysql -u root -p mr_sbc_clean_new < mr_sbc_clean_dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

**To create dump follow below steps:**

1. Open CMD and go to bin folder where you have installed your MySQL
   ex:C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin. If you see in this
   folder mysqldump.exe will be there. Or you have setup above folder
   in    your Path variable of Environment Variable.
2. Now if you hit mysqldump in CMD you can see CMD is able to identify dump command.
3. Now run "**mysqldump -h [host] -P [port] -u [username] -p --skip-triggers --no-create-info --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false ABC_databse > c:\xyz.sql**"
4. Above command will prompt for password then it will start processing.

Answer (score 0):

For example, using [-E(--events)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_events), [-R(--routines)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_routines) and [--triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_triggers) implicitly used by default, you can export the schema and data of the tables of `apple` database with its [events](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html), [routines (procedures and functions)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) and [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) to `backup.sql` as shown below. *[--single-transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) guarantees consistent(reliable) dump and it is impossible to export only procedures or functions and [--skip-triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_triggers) can exclude the triggers which are included with implicit `--triggers` by default and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77363989#77363989) explains how to export the schema and data of the tables of a database:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -E -R --single-transaction apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysqldump -u john -p --events --routines --single-transaction apple > backup.sql
```

Or. *You can explicitly use `--triggers` as shown below::

```
                           ↓↓ Here ↓↓
mysqldump -u john -p -E -R --triggers --single-transaction apple > backup.sql
```

And, using [-B(--databases)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_databases), you can export the schema and data of `apple` and `orange` databases with their events, routines (procedures and functions) and triggers to `backup.sql` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77403680#77403680) explains how to export the schema and data of multiple databases:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -B -E -R --single-transaction apple orange > backup.sql
```

And, using [-A(--all-databases)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_all-databases), you can export the schema and data of all databases with all their events, routines (procedures and functions) and triggers to `backup.sql` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77417921#77417921) explains how to export the schema and data of all databases:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -A -B -E -R --single-transaction > backup.sql
```