# Export MySQL database with triggers and procedures?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, procedure, dump

How to create a MySQL database dump (`.sql` file) with all its triggers and procedures?

Comment: Just add -R option in the mysqldump command.

Comment: Deepanshu is right!, the -R option do the same as --routines=true --triggers=true

Answer (score 169, accepted):

`mysqldump` will backup by *default* all the **triggers** but **NOT** the **stored procedures/functions**. There are 2 mysqldump parameters that control this behavior:

- `--routines` – FALSE by default
- `--triggers` – TRUE by default

so in `mysqldump` command , add `--routines` like :

```
mysqldump <other mysqldump options> --routines > outputfile.sql
```

See the [MySQL documentation about mysqldump arguments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_routines).

Comment: i have MySQL "5.1.48-community" i run "mysqldump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt  > dumpfile.sql;" but it is giving error and error is "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql dump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt  > dum' at
line 1". How to solve it? -

Comment: add to the command " -p -uusername dbname " , and you not need the ";" sign in the end

Comment: Also keep in mind that you should run mysqldump at the shell prompt, not in the MySQL command-line client or in phpMyAdmin or other query tool.

Comment: @HaimEvgi, Why do you say `-routines` instead of `--routines`?

Comment: `--routines` only works however if the user has sufficient access rights to `mysql.proc` table.
`GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc TO '<user>'@'localhost';`

Comment: Does `--routines` include stored functions as well?

Comment: @HaimEvgi will we need --routines while importing also?

Comment: I don't get whose 'reasonable' idea for defaults this was. I find the defaults quite counterintuitive (to include triggers but not to include functions and procedures).

Answer (score 26):

May be it's obvious for expert users of MYSQL but I wasted some time while trying to figure out default value would not export functions. So I thought to mention here that **--routines** param needs to be set to true to make it work.

```
mysqldump --routines=true -u <user> my_database > my_database.sql
```

Comment: You do not need to use --routines=true.  Sprocs are NOT dumped by default.  You simply need to include --routines as per the example in the accepted answer.

Comment: --routines=true and --routines. does the same.

Answer (score 9):

I've created the following script and it worked for me just fine.

```sh
#! /bin/sh
cd $(dirname $0)
DB=$1
DBUSER=$2
DBPASSWD=$3
FILE=$DB-$(date +%F).sql
mysqldump --routines "--user=${DBUSER}"  --password=$DBPASSWD $DB > $PWD/$FILE
gzip $FILE
echo Created $PWD/$FILE*
```

and you call the script using command line arguments.

```
backupdb.sh my_db dev_user dev_password
```

Comment: hi, on line 7 why the variable DBUSER is between "" and the othert are not?

Comment: @rafaelphp, guess it was just an accidental typo. Ideally it is good to surround the values in double quotes to escape certain characters being a part of the values. But there is no hard and stop rule.

Comment: precisely. I would add quotes around all of them for good measure

Answer (score 1):

We can use -R instead of using --routine flag.

```
mysqldump -u mysqluser -R databasename > /tmp/databasename.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, using [-R(--routines)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_routines) and [--triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_triggers) implicitly used by default, you can export the schema and data of the tables of `apple` database with its [routines (procedures and functions)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) and [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) to `backup.sql` as shown below. *It is impossible to export only procedures or functions and [--skip-triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_triggers) can exclude the triggers which are included with implicit `--triggers` by default and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078196/take-perfect-backup-with-mysqldump/77569735#77569735) explains how to perfectly export databases:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -R apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysqldump -u john -p --routines apple > backup.sql
```

Or. *You can explicitly use `--triggers` as shown below:

```
                        ↓↓ Here ↓↓
mysqldump -u john -p -R --triggers apple > backup.sql
```