# Export MySQL dump from command line

Tags: mysql, database, command-line, linode, database-dump

I am moving away from Linode because I don't have the Linux sysadmin skills necessary; before I complete the transition to a more noob-friendly service, I need to export the contents of a MySQL database. Is there a way I can do this from the command line?

Comment: Try: http://www.mediacollege.com/computer/database/mysql/backup.html

Comment: [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 801, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) command-line function.

For example:

If it's an entire DB, then:

```
   $ mysqldump -u [uname] -p db_name > db_backup.sql
```

If it's all DBs, then:

```
   $ mysqldump -u [uname] -p --all-databases > all_db_backup.sql
```

If it's specific tables within a DB, then:

```
   $ mysqldump -u [uname] -p db_name table1 table2 > table_backup.sql
```

You can even go as far as auto-compressing the output using gzip (if your DB is very big):

```
   $ mysqldump -u [uname] -p db_name | gzip > db_backup.sql.gz
```

If you want to do this **remotely** and you have the access to the server in question, then the following would work (presuming the MySQL server is on port 3306):

```
   $ mysqldump -P 3306 -h [ip_address] -u [uname] -p db_name > db_backup.sql
```

It should drop the `.sql` file in the folder you run the command-line from.

**EDIT:** Updated to avoid inclusion of passwords in CLI commands, use the `-p` option without the password. It will prompt you for it and not record it.

Comment: Your answer in conjunction with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989724/how-to-mysqldump-remote-db-from-local-machine   --  Should do what he is asking, since he did include he needs it downloaded.  It's either that or a `wget` or `scp` will be needed to retrieve said file once built.

Comment: Small note that it is safer to not enter the password right in the command. Only using the -p option without password will prompt for the password when run, that way the password is not stored in your command history (and potentially retrieved). So using the following command:  
mysqldump -P 3306 -h [ip_address] -u [uname] -p db_name > db_backup.sql

Comment: How do you specify the ssh port if access is remote? Port is not default 22 in my use case ..

Comment: Instead of using `>` to save, I rather use `-r` in order to prevent trouble with foreign characters, or that nightmare concerning encoding problems, as stated [in this article](https://makandracards.com/makandra/595-dumping-and-importing-from-to-mysql-in-an-utf-8-safe-way).

Comment: For large/actively updated dataases, use --single-transaction parameter. This creates a checkpoint and helps ensure consistency. Also, use switches --routines --triggers, if you have stored procedures/functions/triggers

Comment: You should use `--result-file=db_backup.sql` instead of `> db_backup.sql`. Quote from the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html): "UTF-16 is not permitted as a connection character set (see [Impermissible Client Character Sets](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html#charset-connection-impermissible-client-charset)), so the dump file will not load correctly. To work around this issue, use the `--result-file` option, which creates the output in ASCII format".

Comment: When I run  this command  " >mysqldump -u [uname] -p db_name > db_backup.sql" 
return the Can not connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' error returning.  Mysql is runnig. I can log in  "./mysql -u root" command. thank you already

Comment: NOTE: I'm using MySQL 8 - it should provide an absolute path for the output file
             mysqldump -u [user_name] -p [db_name] > D:\dump\mof_dump.sql

Answer (score 18):

In latest versions of mysql, at least in mine, you cannot put your pass in the command directly.

You have to run:

`mysqldump -u [uname] -p db_name > db_backup.sql`

and then it will ask for the password.

Comment: removing space between `-p` option and actual *password* does the trick

Answer (score 14):

If downloading from remote server, here is a simple example:

```
mysqldump -h my.address.amazonaws.com -u my_username -p db_name > /home/username/db_backup_name.sql
```

The -p indicates you will enter a password, it does not relate to the db_name. After entering the command you will be prompted for the password. Type it in and press enter.

Answer (score 10):

On windows you need to specify the mysql bin where the mysqldump.exe resides.

```
cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin

mysqldump -u[username] -p[password] --all-databases > C:\localhost.sql
```

save this into a text file such as backup.cmd

Comment: or usually having mysql in your PATH variable so you can run `mysql` commands from everywhere without being in it's directory.

Answer (score 3):

Just type `mysqldump` or `mysqldump --help` in your cmd will show `how to use`

Here is my ***cmd result***

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin>mysqldump
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't go inside `mysql`, just open *Command prompt* and directly type this:

```
mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql
```

Comment: Copying the first line of code from the accepted answer on a 5-year old question is a bold strategy for karma farming.

Comment: I tried this MySQLdump command inside Mysql prompt and didn't work. so just answered :-)

Answer (score 3):

Go to MySQL installation directory and open cmd from there.
Then execute the below command to get a backup of your database.

```
mysqldump -u root -p --add-drop-database --databases db> C:\db-dontdelete\db.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the MySQL other than default port:

```
mysqldump.exe -u username -p -P PORT_NO database > backup.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who wants to type password within the command line. It is possible but recommend to pass it inside quotes so that the special character won't cause any issue.

```
mysqldump -h'my.address.amazonaws.com' -u'my_username' -p'password' db_name > /path/backupname.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

**mysqldump**  is another program in the MySQL directory

> Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin

**step 1**: First you have to go to the path and open CMD from the folder.

**step 2**: Then type `mysqldump` in the CMD

---

**it should display as follows**

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

**step 3**: Then type this command

```
mysqldump -u [user_name] -p [database_name] > D:\db_dump.sql
```

*Note :*
*you should provide an absolute path for the output file.*
*Here I provide* `D:\`

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can export the schema and data of the tables of `apple` database to `backup.sql` as shown below. *`backup.sql` is created if it doesn't exist and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql/77379857#77379857) explains how to import the schema and data of the tables of a database and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77384761#77384761), [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77403680#77403680) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77417921#77417921) explain how to export the schema and data of a database, multiple databases and all databases respectively and [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html) explains how to export databases and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078196/take-perfect-backup-with-mysqldump/77569735#77569735) explains how to perfectly export databases:

```
mysqldump -u john -p apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysqldump --user=john --password apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysqldump -u john -p apple -r backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysqldump --user=john --password apple --result-file=backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -r backup.sql apple
```

Or:

```
mysqldump --user=john --password --result-file=backup.sql apple
```

Then, you need to input a password after running the command above:

```
Enter password:
```

In addition, you can export the schema and data of the tables of `apple` database to `backup.sql` without a password prompt by setting a password(e.g., `banana`) to [-p(--password=)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_password) as shown below. *Don't put any space just after `-p`(`--password=`) because there is error and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293042/how-to-perform-a-mysqldump-without-a-password-prompt/77466101#77466101) explains how to export a database without a password prompt in detail:

```
mysqldump -u john -pbanana apple > backup.sql
```

And, using [-d(--no-data)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data), you can export only the schema of the tables of `apple` database to `backup.sql` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175473/mysql-export-schema-without-data/77364432#77364432) explains how to export only schema more:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -d apple > backup.sql
```

And, using [-t(--no-create-info)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-create-info) and [-c(--complete-insert)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_complete-insert), you can export only the data of the specific tables `person` and `animal` of `apple` database to `backup.sql` with [INSERT statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) which has column names as shown below. *By default, `INSERT` statement doesn't have column names and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109993/dump-only-the-data-with-mysqldump-without-any-table-information/77371448#77371448) explains how to export only data more:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -t -c apple person animal > backup.sql
```

And, using `-t`(`--no-create-info`), `-c`(`--complete-insert`) and [--ignore-table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table), you can export only the data of the tables except `person` and `animal` tables of `apple` database to `backup.sql` with `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425158/how-to-skip-certain-database-tables-with-mysqldump/77427791#77427791) explains how to export databases except some tables more:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -t -c apple --ignore-table=apple.person --ignore-table=apple.animal > backup.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, using [-B(--databases)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_databases), you can export the schema and data of `apple` database to `backup.sql` as shown below. *`backup.sql` is created if it doesn't exist and `-B`(`--databases`) can export one or more databases and generates the schema `CREATE DATABASE apple;` and `USE apple;` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql/77393012#77393012) explains how to import the schema and data of a database and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77403680#77403680), [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77417921#77417921) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77363989#77363989) explain how to export the schema and data of multiple databases, all databases and the tables of a database respectively and [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html) explains how to export databases and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078196/take-perfect-backup-with-mysqldump/77569735#77569735) explains how to perfectly export databases:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -B apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysqldump -u john -p --databases apple > backup.sql
```

In addition, using [-d(--no-data)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data), you can export only the schema of `apple` database to `backup.sql` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175473/mysql-export-schema-without-data/77364432#77364432) explains how to export only schema more:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -B -d apple > backup.sql
```

Or, using [-t(--no-create-info)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-create-info) and [-c(--complete-insert)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_complete-insert), you can export only the data of `apple` database to `backup.sql` with [INSERT statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) which has column names as shown below. *By default, `INSERT` statement doesn't have column names and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109993/dump-only-the-data-with-mysqldump-without-any-table-information/77371448#77371448) explains how to export only data more:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -B -t -c apple > backup.sql
```

Be careful, using `-t`(`--no-create-info`) and `-c`(`--complete-insert`), you cannot properly export only the data of the specific tables `person` and `animal` of `apple` database to `backup.sql` with `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below:

So, this below gets error:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -B -t -c apple person animal > backup.sql
```

> mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'person' when selecting the database

And, this below lacks the schema `CREATE DATABASE apple;` and `USE apple;` because `-B`(`--databases`) is overridden by [--tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tables) which excludes the schema `CREATE DATABASE apple;` and `USE apple;`:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -B -t -c apple --tables person animal > backup.sql
```

But, using `-t`(`--no-create-info`), `-c`(`--complete-insert`) and [--ignore-table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table), you can properly export only the data of `apple` database except `apple` database's `person` and `animal` tables to `backup.sql` with `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425158/how-to-skip-certain-database-tables-with-mysqldump/77427791#77427791) explains how to export databases except some tables more:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -B -t -c apple --ignore-table=apple.person --ignore-table=apple.animal > backup.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the database named `archiedb`, use this:

```
mysql -p <password for the database> --databases archiedb > /home/database_backup.sql
```

Assuming this is Linux, choose where the backup file will be saved.

Comment: shell>mysqldump -p mypassword --databases mydb>/home/backup.sql.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users you can go to your mysql folder to run the command

e.g.

```
cd c:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.26\bin
mysqldump -u root -p databasename > dbname_dump.sql
```

Comment: The question suggested that MySQL is running on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This step only comes after dumping your MySQL file(which most of the answers above have addressed).

It assumes that you have the said dump file in your remote server and now you want to bring it down to your local computer.

To download the dumped `.sql` file from your remote server to your local computer, do

```
scp -i YOUR_SSH_KEY your_username@IP:name_of_file.sql ./my_local_project_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

For some versions of MySQL try.

```
sudo mysqldump [database name] > db_backup.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

10 years have passed since the topic was created, and during this time new utilities have appeared that resolve the main **problem** of `mysqldump` - **performance**.

## mysqlsh

`mysqlsh` is a new universal **shell** for database administration. Unlike the classic mysql client, which allows you to simply execute SQL queries, `mysqlsh` can work in *SQL* \ *Python* \ *JS* mode and, most importantly, it has access to specialized database objects: *dba, utils, shell*. Through these objects you can **access** specialized **administration tools**.

The util object allows you to dump like this:

```bash
mysqlsh --mysql -u adm -h localhost -P 3306 -e "util.dumpInstance('/tmp/sample-backup-instane')"
```

To restore the dump

```bash
mysqlsh --mysql -u adm -h localhost -P 3306 -e "util.loadInstance('/tmp/sample-backup-instane')"
```

Unlike export via `mysqldump`, export via `mysqlsh` is performed in **several threads** (4 by default), which can significantly speed up dump creation.

*Note, by default, dumps are created in TSV format (not .SQL)*

## mydumper

`mydumper` is a command line utility created by the community ([link to GitHub](https://github.com/mydumper/mydumper)). Unlike `mysqlsh` it is easier to use, because it is a highly specialized tool.

The dump created by the `mydumper` utility can be restored either manually by `mysql` or using the `myloader` utility, which works in conjunction with `mydumper`.

```bash
mydumper -u adm -p pass
```

This command creates a subdirectory with a set of `.sql` files, where each file corresponds to a table. To download this dump into an empty database use:

```bash
myloader --directory=export-20230916-151241
```

---

[mysqlsh documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-dump-instance-schema.html)

[mydumper docs](https://github.com/mydumper/mydumper/tree/master/docs)

[More examples about backup via mysqlsh or mydumper](https://sqlbak.com/blog/mysql-command-line-backup-top-5-cli-utilities/)

Answer (score 0):

For example, using [-B(--databases)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_databases), you can export the schema and data of `apple` and `orange` databases to `backup.sql` with as shown below. *`backup.sql` is created if it doesn't exist and `-B`(`--databases`) can export one or more databases and generates the schema `CREATE DATABASE <db>;` and `USE <db>;` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql/77404295#77404295) explains how to import the schema and data of multiple databases and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77417921#77417921), [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77384761#77384761) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77363989#77363989) explain how to export the schema and data of all databases, a database and the tables of a database respectively and [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html) explains how to export databases and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078196/take-perfect-backup-with-mysqldump/77569735#77569735) explains how to perfectly export databases:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -B apple orange > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysqldump -u john -p --databases apple orange > backup.sql
```

In addition, using [-d(--no-data)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data), you can export only the schema of `apple` and `orange` databases to `backup.sql` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175473/mysql-export-schema-without-data/77364432#77364432) explains how to export only schema more:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -B -d apple orange > backup.sql
```

Or, using [-t(--no-create-info)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-create-info) and [-c(--complete-insert)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_complete-insert), you can export only the data of `apple` and `orange` databases to `backup.sql` with [INSERT statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) which has column names as shown below. *By default, `INSERT` statement doesn't have column names and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109993/dump-only-the-data-with-mysqldump-without-any-table-information/77371448#77371448) explains how to export only data more:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -B -t -c apple orange > backup.sql
```

Be careful, using `-t`(`--no-create-info`) and `-c`(`--complete-insert`), you cannot export only the data of the specific tables `person` and `animal` of `apple` and `orange` databases to `backup.sql` with `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below:

So, this below gets error:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -B -t -c apple orange person animal > backup.sql
```

> mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'person' when selecting the database

And, this below with [--tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tables) gets error:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -B -t -c apple orange --tables person animal > backup.sql
```

> mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "orange"

But, using `-t`(`--no-create-info`), `-c`(`--complete-insert`) and [--ignore-table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table), you can export only the data of `apple` and `orange` databases except `apple` database's `person` table and `orange` database's `animal` table to `backup.sql` with `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425158/how-to-skip-certain-database-tables-with-mysqldump/77427791#77427791) explains how to export databases except some tables more:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -B -t -c apple orange --ignore-table=apple.person --ignore-table=orange.animal > backup.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are exporting from one cloud provider and importing into another cloud provider, such as Amazon RDS, and you are using MySQL (not MariaDB), then you have to take heed of GTIDs as well, which could be set for failover and scaleout behavior in an instance that is using MySQL replication with Global Transaction Identifiers (GTIDs). Remember MySQL instances on the cloud are **Managed Services**. They do not give you root access to the MySQL Instance; otherwise, it can cause instability in their platform. So they do not allow you to explicitly define global variables in a SQL file. This becomes an inssue when you do an import and you get an error like this:

> Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER,
> SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for
> this operation

If you are using MySQL and not MariaDB, you can set the set-gtid-purged flag to OFF to your mysqldump command to prevent such access denied errors:

```
mysqldump --set-gtid-purged=OFF -h [host] -u [uname] -p dbName > dump.sql
```

Answer (score -1):

For example, using [`-A`(--all-databases)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_all-databases), you can export the schema and data of all databases including [mysql system database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/system-schema.html) to `backup.sql` as shown below. *`backup.sql` is created if it doesn't exist and `-A`(`--all-databases`) can also export `mysql` system database and generates the schema `CREATE DATABASE <db>;` and `USE <db>;` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql/77422773#77422773) explains how to import the schema and data of all databases and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77403680#77403680), [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77384761#77384761) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77363989#77363989) explain how to export the schema and data of multiple databases, a database and the tables of a database respectively and [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html) explains how to export databases and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078196/take-perfect-backup-with-mysqldump/77569735#77569735) explains how to perfectly export databases:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -A > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysqldump -u john -p --all-databases > backup.sql
```

In addition, you can export only the schema of all databases to `backup.sql` with [`-d`(`--no-data`)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data) as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175473/mysql-export-schema-without-data/77364432#77364432) explains how to export only schema more:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -A -d > backup.sql
```

Or, using [`-t`(`--no-create-info`)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-create-info) and [`-c`(`--complete-insert`)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_complete-insert), you can export only the data of all databases to `backup.sql` with [INSERT statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) which has column names as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109993/dump-only-the-data-with-mysqldump-without-any-table-information/77371448#77371448) explains how to export only data more:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -A -t -c > backup.sql
```

Be careful, using `-t`(`--no-create-info`) and `-c`(`--complete-insert`), you cannot export only the data of the specific tables `person` and `animal` of all databases to `backup.sql` with `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below:

So, these below export nothing without error:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -A -t -c person animal > backup.sql
```

```
mysqldump -u john -p -A -t -c --tables person animal > backup.sql
```

But, using `-t`(`--no-create-info`), `-c`(`--complete-insert`) and [--ignore-table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table), you can export only the data of all databases except `apple` database's `person` table and `orange` database's `animal` table to `backup.sql` with `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425158/how-to-skip-certain-database-tables-with-mysqldump/77427791#77427791) explains how to export databases except some tables more:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -A -t -c --ignore-table=apple.person --ignore-table=orange.animal > backup.sql
```

Comment: You really like to repeat yourself   "...... and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77417921/724039), [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77417921/724039) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77417921/724039) explain ... ", do you ?

Answer (score -2):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "datestamp=%YYYY%.%MM%.%DD%.%HH%.%Min%.%Sec%"
set drive=your backup folder
set databaseName=your databasename
set user="your database user"
set password="your database password"
subst Z: "C:\Program Files\7-Zip" 
subst M: "D:\AppServ\MySQL\bin"
set zipFile="%drive%\%databaseName%-%datestamp%.zip"
set sqlFile="%drive%\%databaseName%-%datestamp%.sql"
M:\mysqldump.exe --user=%user% --password=%password% --result-file="%sqlFile%" --databases %databaseName%
@echo Mysql Backup Created
Z:\7z.exe a -tzip "%zipFile%" "%sqlFile%"
@echo File Compress End
del %sqlFile%
@echo Delete mysql file
pause;
```