# Moving MySQL database from local MAMP server to host's server

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I've developed WP site locally using MAMP. I know how to transfer WP site to server using FTP but problem is how I get MySQL DB to server. Before I've done this in cPanel and that's easy. Now there's no option to use cPanel or phpMyAdmin on the host. I can get connection to server with FTP and SHH. So is it possible to move DB from MAMP to server somehow? If not what should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can export your database.

Comment: You mean I export my database from MAMP's phpMyAdmin? Then I get ```myWPdatabase.sql```. Do I just have to move this file to server with FTP and thats it or?

Comment: Use duplicator plugin ;) easy thing. Just will be need database name, user name & password.

Comment: Yes. However what you do is save it locally on your computer, then import it from the PC to phpmyadmin after.

Comment: I think I'm not able to use phpMyAdmin in the hosts server. There's no cPanel or other similar thing. @Earid I watched couple tutorial how to use Duplicator and they had cPanel on the host, and we're able to use phpMyAdmin. Can I use install site with Duplicator to host's server without phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I belive they mentioned cpanel/phpmyadmin to use database uer name, pass etc. As you already have it, no longer need to use phpmyadmin or cpanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could FTP the export of your SQL dump file to your live server, then if you have SSH access and can connect to the MySQL command line, you could import your SQL dump file.  This article should be helpful:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/downloading-mysql-dump-from-command-line)

You didn't specify what type of live server you're running, that information would be helpful!

Comment: I will try this later and then come back to answer what happened. Sorry I don't know what you mean with "what type of live server you're running", I use MAMP but maybe thats not what you're asking.

Comment: when you move the files locally from your MAMP and FTP them to another server, what is the Operating System of that server you FTP to?

Comment: It appeared that mysql is additional service with this service provider. It didn't come to my mind because previously databases has been included to basic services. Now I can import sql.