# dump.sql contanins also events

Tags: mysql, database, dump, mysql-event, database-dump

I just want to know if, when I create a backup (`dump.sql`) of my MySQL db, it will contains also events that I create and that perform changes in my db for example every day. The events will be stored in the database information_schema so I'm not sure that with the backup of my db I save also the events...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can, but only if you include the `--events` option.

Or, in MySQL Administrator:

[image: dump events]

Comment: but I do the dump from mysql administrator. Do I have to use the shell?

Comment: @user - there should be an checkbox in the mysql administrator backup screen to choose whether or not to include events (right by the "Create Dump in a Single Transaction" and "Dump Stored Routines" boxes)

Comment: this is the screen with the advanced options...I can't see anything about events....http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/7282/catturavo.png

Comment: @user - Sorry, my comment originally said on the advanced tab, but it's actually on the "Object Selection" tab.  Looking at your screenshot, it looks like you still have the original MySQL Administrator tool.  If you upgrade to MySQL Workbench, you should see the new option for exporting events.

Comment: ok, with mysql workbench I found the option! :) another thing... with the shell how can I do?

Comment: I have to write 
mysqldump --events db_name > name.sql right? but this does not work...

Comment: @user - not sure exactly, but if you run a backup through mysql workbench it will actually show the command line that is used, so you could just copy that and use it.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line , run the mysqldump command with --noevents flag

```
mysqldump -u username -p --events dbname > anyfilename.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, using [-E](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_events) or [--events](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_events), you can export the schema and data of the tables of `apple` database with its [events](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) to `backup.sql` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078196/take-complete-backup-with-mysqldump/77569735#77569735) explains how to perfectly export databases:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -E apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysqldump -u john -p --events apple > backup.sql
```