# Export database with procedures using mysqldump

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, procedure, dump

While exporting databases using mysqldump like this:

```
mysqldump -u mysqluser -p mysqlpassword databasename > /tmp/databasename.sql
```

Will this command also export stored procedures that listed using the following command:

```sql
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE db = 'databasename';
```

If not, how to export mysql database using mysqldump along with its associated stored procedures from the Linux terminal? Also note that I cannot use phpMyAdmin for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

`mysqldump -u mysqluser -p mysqlpassword --routines databasename > /tmp/databasename.sql`

Refer this link : http://www.ducea.com/2007/07/25/dumping-mysql-stored-procedures-functions-and-triggers/

Answer (score 0):

We can use the -R flag as a substitute for --routines flag while dumping as the other answer suggest.

```
mysqldump -u mysqluser -p mysqlpassword -R databasename > /tmp/databasename.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, using [-R(--routines)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_routines), you can export the schema and data of the tables of `apple` database with its [routines (procedures and functions)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) to `backup.sql` as shown below. *It is impossible to export only procedures or functions and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078196/take-perfect-backup-with-mysqldump/77569735#77569735) explains how to perfectly export databases:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -R apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysqldump -u john -p --routines apple > backup.sql
```